# Displaying hidden value using id selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I have an hidden input that is saving the value for total from db. Which is working fine.

```
<td><input type="hidden" id="total" class="total" value='{{=total}}' /></td>
```

Then I am trying to display this value in a total box by using following

```
<td>$<input type="text" name="sum"  readyonly id="gtotal" onload="getTotal()" value="" /></td>
```

The jquery function gtotal is .

```
function getTotal() {
    $("#gtotal").load(document.getElementById('total'));
}
```

But this doesnt display anything onload. Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: change your code in getTotal() function $("#gtotal").val(document.getElementById('total').value);

Comment: also in html if your textbox is read only then your code would be <input type="text" name="sum"  readonly="readonly" id="gtotal" onload="getTotal()" value="" />

Comment: What does your developer console say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#gtotal").load(document.getElementById('total'));
```

Will not work

try the following:

```
function getTotal() {

        $("#gtotal").val($('#total').val());
    }
```

What you are doing is simply reloading the element and rather than calling the value, you are calling the object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value like

```
function getTotal() {
    $("#gtotal").val($('#total').val());
}
```

And call this function on load of either the `DOM` load like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   getTotal();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$("#gtotal").load(document.getElementById('total'));
```

with

```
$("#gtotal").val(document.getElementById('total').value);
```

> notice the function `.val()` and the `.value` in the end of the line

and

```
document.getElementById('total').value
```

with

```
$('#total').val()
```

> Since you are already using jQuery

That will make your code look like

```
$("#gtotal").val($('#total').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

call the function in `<script>` tag.

```
function getTotal() {
    $("#gtotal").val($('#total').val());
}

getTotal();
```

Demo: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7cG4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use load ... this code block will not work for you to get value

```
  function getTotal() {
   $("#gtotal").load(document.getElementById('total'));
}
```

for jQuery

```
 function getTotal() {
$("#gtotal").val($('#total').val());
}
```

for JavaScript

```
function getTotal() {
   document.getElementById("gtotal").value=document.getElementById('total').value;
}
```

be sure both input field should be on same page

Comment: And call getTotal() directly After the code block or you can use
<body onload='getTotal()'>